# Passing array to function by value or reference the same?

Tags: c, arrays, reference

I want to know if there is any real difference; I have written code that as it feel it a passing by copy not reference but it acts as reference.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int pause = 0;

void display(int b[5], int size){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("\n%d",b[i]," at:");
        printf(" %d", &b[i]);
    }
}

void main(){

    int num[] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };
    printf("\nIn main function.");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("\n%d", num[i], " at:");
        printf(" %d", &num[i]);
    }
    display(num,5);

    scanf("%d", pause);
}
```

Comment: c does not pass by reference.  You can pass by pointer, though.

Comment: @JGroven The term "pass by reference" is still valid though. It is just the implementation uses pointers.

Comment: @John3136 I agree, it's a minor linguistic nuance, but I think it's important just to note that C doesn't use references in the way C++ does.

Comment: it is actually explained in any elementary C book or online tutorial

Comment: @John3136 "pass by reference" is a valid term, but it does not apply to C.  Passing pointers by value -- which is the closest thing C affords -- has slightly different semantics.

Comment: `printf(" %d", &num[i]);` causes undefined behaviour by using the wrong format specifier

Comment: @JohnBollinger In C you can implement the programming concept "pass by reference" by passing pointers. IMO it is unhelpful to say that pass by reference is not possible in C.

Comment: @M.M, passing pointers by value is indeed similar to pass-by-reference, but it is *not* the same thing.  Notably, in pass-by-reference the called function can always expect to receive a valid reference to an object, but the analog is not guaranteed when passing pointers by value.  Perhaps it is a bit pedantic to point out the distinction, but it is relevant, and important to understand.

Comment: Arrays **cannot** be passed by value in C.  Only pointers to arrays can be used as function arguments.  Sometimes this is obscured (because you can write `foo(int a[])`), but there's no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an array itself to a function *at all*, nor can you return one.  In particular, despite the appearance of its declaration, your function `display()` does not receive an array as a parameter.  It's declaration is 100% equivalent to this one:

```
void display(int *b, int size);
```

and this one:

```
void display(int b[], int size);
```

Expressions of array type are automatically converted to pointers in almost every context in which they can appear, so this function call:

> ```
> display(num,5);
> ```

is equivalent to

```
display(&num[0],5);
```

Nevertheless, there is a potential difference to call out in this area: the expression `&num` is *not* equivalent to `&num[0]`.  They refer to the same address, but the two expressions have different types.  Passing the former would be the analog of passing the array by reference, but that expression does not have the correct type for the first argument to your `display()` function.  A function that wants to receive &num needs to be declared differently:

```
void display2(int (*b)[5]);
```

or

```
void display3(int n, int (*b)[n]);
```

The latter requires C99, or C2011 with VLA support (which is required in C99, but optional in C2011).

Comment: So there is no mechanism to pass values of an array to a function by copying method? The pointer(reference) of the array is passed onto the function and it using that memory address to go through the elements location?

Comment: @KamalAhmad if what you want is to pass the array itself, then you have understood me correctly: there is no mechanism for passing a copy of the array elements.  Of course, the receiving function can explicitly make a copy itself.  However, an array can be a member of a structure, and structures (not just pointers to them) can be function arguments, and therefore passed by value, resulting in all members, including array members, being copied.